# e.preventdefault() equivalent to replace typed text in java (Android)

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery

I have a function in jQuery/javascript, to type replace any typed text in an input by a specific text :

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
count++;
if (count == "1") { $("input").val("y");}
else if (count == "2") { $("input").val("ye");}
else if (count == "3") { $("input").val("yes");}
else {return false;}
```

(replace anything typed by 'yes' and does nothing after the user types more letters)

I would like to implement the same function in an Android project on a text input. What would be the best way? I don't want to do it in a webview but in native android.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to do what you want.

Just do

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

and it should work for you. You'd have to extend the `TextWatcher` class yourself to do this.

You'd probably want to put your logic into the `afterTextChanged` method of your custom `TextWatcher`.